# How to display two html elements seamlessly

Tags: html, css

My web page displays youtube iframe,say YOUTUBE, and a horizontal div element, say CAPTION. In detail, respecting the vertical order, the top of CAPTION follows just after the bottom of YOUTUBE. The two are almost connected. However they have some narrow room between. And I don't need it. How can you remove the unnecessary room between the two?
Here follows the code and the image of the web page.
For the code, the first `<div>` represents the YOUTUBE and `<demo-caption>` represents CAPTION which is a google polymer element which only has a div element. I guess that you don't need to understand google polymer to answer my question.
In more detail, I have not necessarily applied any css for the page except centering the two elements.

```
               <div id="player" class="main" ></div>
　　　　　　　　<demo-caption ></demo-caption>
```

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-aNsxzNAaTDSFZEcGpPTTYzMnM/view]

Comment: The player div or demo caption probably have some padding or margin. If you remove or override this it will fit directly. If you could add the allplied css classes someone could give you a hint.

Comment: @mxlse, Thank you for the information. I have no css to necessarily apply for the web page except centering the two elements.

Comment: There is always *some* CSS in effect on a page by default.  Specifically what the rules are is determined by what browser you're using.  That's what you're likely seeing with your question -- some margin or padding setting.  (You can find out for sure, at least in Firefox, by using getComputedStyle() on the elements.)  If you want the margin or padding to be different than the default, you can set it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to inspect the two elements to see if they have any unnecessary padding or margins, you can do this in chrome via ctrl+shift+I or right clicking on the element.

in addition you can always use minus margins to change your divs positions

```
demo-caption{
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

or use a relative position

```
demo-caption{
    position:relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```